# When to use different DataContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've been developing ASP.NET MVC applications for quite some time now. And in all of my projects I had only one data context but I encounter some projects that uses different data contexts for different entities. I can't think of any use of it. As far as I'm aware, they work in different transactions so that when a CRUD operation throws exception, rollbacks for the past CRUD operations couldn't be made since they would be committed by that time.

The only cases that I think different contexts should be used is that when you need to separate the transaction scopes or when you deal with more than one database. So my questions are:

1) What's the logic of having different data contexts for different entities?

2) When do you use different data contexts?

Comment: This is too broad to answer as there may be various reasons to do so. Can't you ask the creators of the projects that show this behaviour?

Comment: To Shrink EF Models with DDD Bounded Contexts: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx

Comment: @Colin +1 Nice approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a large project, especially one that worked on by multiple developers, it's often easier to have different data contexts. They can contain only the entities that you need for a particular feature set.

For example, if you are persisting shopping cart data to a database temporarily, you just need the shopping cart objects (cart item list, wish list, etc) you don't need all the objects involved in customer manaagement, order fulfillment, emails sent to customers, etc.

This also makes like easier if you have developers working on different parts of the project. They can all edit their particular data context without messing with everyone else. This comes  in very handy when trying to merge data using SVN.

Comment: I wouldn't separate business logic with using different data contexts, creating data contexts is cheap unless you have hundreds or thousands of entities but I got the reason behind having multiple data contexts, thanks..

Answer (score 0):

One would be for ReadOnly/lightweight access and the other more of a full blown access with all the goodies that come with it.

but certainly, different data contexts generally mean different DB's.